# Translating "It came out carrying infants"

Tags: sentence-translation

I need to have the following translated into Latin:

> It came out carrying infants.

Can anyone help please. The context is a description of an illustration showing something coming out of a small cabin carrying two small infants.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the site! Although generally we appreciate evidence of self-translation before asking your question, I will provide my suggestion below. Please keep that in mind moving forward.

> It came out carrying infants.
>
> *Ferens infantes emersit.*

**Grammatical Breakdown**

- *Ferens*: This is a present active participle meaning "carrying" and modifies the implied subject of *emersit*
- *infantes*: This is a accusative plural noun that is the object of *ferens* and means "infants"
- *emersit*: This is a singular perfect active indicative verb meaning "it came out"

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand your comment about self-translation. By self-translation do you mean evidence that I have attempted to translate into Latin using some translation software?

Comment: @ChrisG Not necessarily software. Just your own personal suggestion as to what you think the translation would be. You can use online or physical dictionaries to fin the vocabulary and whatnot. We are more than willing to help, we just have that policy so that we do not become the more accurate version of Google Translate. :)

Comment: Hi. OK I understand, but as I have no schooling in Latin the only source I can find is what is available online such as the various translation websites that are listed in a Google type search. I am aware that Google translate and others like this are very inaccurate, but what can those of us that have no lnowledge of Latin do? If I enter an English sentence into Google translate and, say, two other similar programs I get different answers in Latin. I have no idea which if any is correct. I am writing a novel and have a few sentences that I need to be accurately translated into Latin.

Comment: @ChrisG Here is what I recommend. I completely understand not wanting to learn a whole new language just to write a few sentences. [Here is a question about dictionaries you can use.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/867/which-online-latin-dictionaries-should-i-use-and-why) Try looking up words individually and then use Wiktionary to conjugate. All we really need is perhaps some of your suggestions as to words that could be used. You do not need to even put them in the right form, just a little evidence that you did your own research is sufficient to meet guidelines!

Comment: I have done some homework regarding this subject and have some Latin translations for the English phrases I have. perhaps you can comment on whether you think they are accurate.Nam eum hinc ferunt

Comment: Sorry, that last post was cut off short. 1. For they beareth him hence - Nam eum hinc ferunt. Context is a group of men carrying another man away from danger. 2. It is forbidden to conceal beasts of little intellect within the folds of your garment - Animae celare bestias exiguae laxis vestibus illicitus est. Context - A man smuggling animals into a religious building, being warned by a saint that if he is to accept holy orders he is to take it seriously and not hide animals in his clothing. 3. The Devil does not like to be recognised - Diabolo se agnosci non placet.

Comment: Final phrases - 4. For they eateth that which eateth them - Nam idem quod eos edit edunt. Context - The notion that humans eat creatures that sometimes eat humans, such as parasites and worms. 5. It came out carrying infants - Ferens infantes exit. Context - a sinister old woman emerging from a building carrying infants.

Comment: @ChrisG If you want confirmation on those, why don't you make them a separate question? It will be easier for people to answer that way.